# How can Professor Crater recognize the M-113 creature

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I've just started Star Trek : The Original Series, and in "The Man Trap", when Professor Crater is being interrogated, he admits that he can recognize the shape-shifting creature from the  M-113 planet in whatever form it takes. How was he able to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crater's wife, Nancy, was killed/replaced by the creature years ago.
Remember that the creature appears as a different person to who ever looks at it. (So it's powers must be psionic/empathic in nature)
Crater said that the creature still appears to him as Nancy out of true affection so that's why he was able to ascertain the creature was impersonating McCoy.
And Crater also spent years with the creature, so he must have become very familiar with it.

The real question, to me, is why did Crater choose to have a fake relationship with a creature that killed his wife?

Comment: *"why did Crater choose to have a fake relationship"*  I think it is pretty much summed up in [this page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Man_Trap_%28episode%29) in the description of Act 4 - 'companionship'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Well... that must have been some pretty amazing "companionship" ...

Comment: @djm Think of it as an extreme form of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erotic_asphyxiation), but involving the creature's natural ability.   (Wikipedia, no images, but still some level of NSFW) >_<

Comment: Greetings from 2023! I think your "real question"is the theme of that show. Yes, he chooses to live with a monster rather than live without the woman whom, ironically, the creature killed. Somehow IIRC this theme was not hit as hard as it should have been.